# Tweepy is accessing my own timeline instead of the specified user's

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to scrape tweets from specific users using tweepy. But instead of giving me the tweets from the user I specify, tweepy returns my own timeline tweets. What am I doing wrong?

```html
tweets = []

def username_tweets_to_csv(username,count):
    try:      
        tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,user_id=username).items(count)

        tweets_list = [[tweet.created_at, tweet.id, tweet.text] for tweet in tweets]

        tweets_df = pd.DataFrame(tweets_list,columns=['Datetime', 'Tweet Id', 'Text'])

        tweets_df.to_csv('/Users/Carla/Documents/CODE_local/{}-tweets.csv'.format(username), sep=',', index = False)

    except BaseException as e:
          print('failed on_status,',str(e))
          time.sleep(3)

username = "jack"
count = 100

username_tweets_to_csv(username, count)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just able to fix it by exchanging the "user_id" parameter for "screen_name". Works perfectly now!

```html
        tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,screen_name=username).items(count)
```